# Which statement is correct?

Tags: difference, sentence-choice

Which statement is correct?

> I want to recreate her look to as nearly possible as I can.
>
> I want to recreate as nearly as possible as I can her look.

Answer (score 2):

Neither is idiomatic.

The second is particularly odd because it has such a huge gap between the verb "recreate" and its direct object "her look." It is not ungrammatical to separate verb and object, but it is idiomatic to keep the separation relatively short. It probably is ungrammatical to have that triple "as."

Moreover, both are redundant, and "nearly" does not strike me as the very best word in this context. Here are some idiomatic variants that have slightly different meanings,

> I want to recreate her look as closely as possible

This does not necessarily mean that I personally want to be the one doing it.

> I want to recreate her look as closely as I can

This does not imply that my capacity to do so is the best available.